# Phonegap running on apple device

Tags: cordova

After the PhoneGap app is built, when it is running on an apple device, is it running inside a browser or a browser control with a local web server? because it is just html/javascript, it should be hosted in a webserver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local html/css/js files in your project. This is just loaded with an UIWebview, PhoneGap only does make some native features possible to use with javascript.